# Value of unintialized automatic variables

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I have this code:

```
int a,b;

int* aPtr = &a;

int* bPtr = &b;

std::cout << "a: " << *aPtr << std::endl;
std::cout << "b: " << *bPtr << std::endl;
```

When I don't assign a value to a/b:

the value of *aPtr is `1984125892` & the value of *bPtr is `4285552`.

Why is this?

Comment: Because both `a` and `b` are uninitialized. You have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not assign a value to the variable `a and b` then it is **undefined behavior**. And you can expect any **garbage value** as a result. A pointer shows the address of a variable and when you say that `int a` then it means you are assigning some memory to the variable `a`. So you need to initialize the variable `a` else it would result in **undefined behavior**. And when you will print the result it would show any **garbage value**.

Comment: Formally, you can't expect anything. In practice you get a garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a tool that shows the adress of a variable in the memory, not the variable itself. `int a` means you reserve some memory (which can be filled with other stuff from previous programs). So you have to initialize (give a beginning value) to `a` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default initialization value for integers in C++ unlike in other languages that initialize with 0.
The pointers in your case just point to some memory location and the values reflect whatever is in that location, which can change depending on a plethora of factors.

Comment: Java, for example, does not have default initialization for local variables. It's probably the same for a lot of languages.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ Java is a whole different story. In Java all variables are references, this is not the case in c++. That one has to initialize varaibles only applies to (integral?) types in c++. Normal objects become (default) constructed.

Answer (score -1):

`a` and `b` are contained on the stack. If you do not assign any value to them, they will have just the values that were at the stack as the space for them was allocated / reserved. This related to pointers at all.